# Objective C: Register file extension

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am creating an app which needs to be opened if a user double clicks on a file with a certain extension.. How do i register the file extension with my app? and then read the contents?.

E.G the file could have the extension words.ThisApp and it could be in XML Format.. how could I read that in objective c into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read the [Document-Based Applications Overview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Documents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000006i).

To register an extension to your application, bring up the Target info window (*Project* » *Edit Current Target "My Target"...* at the bottom) and open the "Properties" tab. Fill in the blanks for your document type there. For more info, read [Storing document type informations in the Application's Property List](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000024-BHADAGHF), contained inside the above guide.

To read XML data, consider using a [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (google it for examples) to drive the results into a `NSMutableArray` as you see fit; and to get the data into your application, consider using a `NSDocument` subclass, as suggested (again) in the document-based application overview.

As you might understand, this document is quite a vital read.

Comment: Author doesn't say if this is iOS or Mac OS X.  If Mac OS X, NSXMLDocument might be easier than NSXMLParser.